# Node-webkit execute external command?

Tags: node.js, bash, node-webkit

How to execute system command in node-webkit (or node.js) external process parallel of current script.

I'm trying to use child_process. After interruption of my script subprocess is exit. However i need a simple way execute bash command without output or with output but without program stop when my script will be interrupted.

I need a correct simple way.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `detached` option in spawn/execute arguments:

> If the detached option is set, the child process will be made the
>   leader of a new process group. This makes it possible for the child to
>   continue running after the parent exits.
>
> By default, the parent will wait for the detached child to exit. To
>   prevent the parent from waiting for a given child, use the
>   child.unref() method, and the parent's event loop will not include the
>   child in its reference count.
>
> Example of detaching a long-running process and redirecting its output
>   to a file:

```
 var fs = require('fs'),
     spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
     out = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a'),
     err = fs.openSync('./out.log', 'a');

 var child = spawn('prg', [], {
   detached: true,
   stdio: [ 'ignore', out, err ]
 });

 child.unref();
```